# jquery toggle between 3 states and post a ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, toggle, states

I need to toggle between 3 states

- state #1: Unselected just grey background
- state #2: Selected set background to green
- state #2: Clicked again, set background to red
  Now on every click toggle between red and green

How would this be possible?
Beside changing a class I also need to make an ajax call at the same time.

What I basically just want is a selected, not selected toggle and 
I have no idea how to detect is a user clicked the grey box the first time

For starters I now have:

```
<div id="test" onclick => "$(this).toggleClass('selected_yes')"> test <div>
```

Comment: `Toggle` implies two states. You cannot toggle between 3 states. You'll need to manually cycle through them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can still use `toggle`:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    if (this.className.match(/green|red/)) $(this).toggleClass('green red');
    else  $(this).toggleClass('green');

    // ajax call here
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DRZY2/

Comment: thanks for all the answers had to choose this one, since its the shortest and most efficient coded solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this), state = $this.data('state') || '';
    if(state == ''){
        $this.addClass('greyBg'); 
        $this.data('state', 'unselected');   
    }
    else if(state == 'unselected'){ 
        $this.removeClass('greyBg').addClass('greenBg');
        $this.data('state', 'selected');
    }
    else if(state == 'selected'){
        $this.removeClass('greyBg greenBg').addClass('redBg');
        $this.data('state', 'clicked');
    } 
    else{
        if($this.hasClass('redBg')){
             $this.removeClass('redBg').addClass('greenBg');
        }
        else{
             $this.removeClass('greenBg').addClass('redBg');
        }

        //Here you can make ajax call now
    }

});
```

Every time you click I am maintaining its state using jQuery `data` method and also executing the required logic. I hope this makes sense to you.

Define the required classes with appropriate styles.

```
.greyBg   { background-color: grey; }
.greenBg  { background-color: green; }
.redBg    { background-color: red; }
```

Comment: @Rubytastic - Did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have three classes:

```
.unselected { background-color: grey; }
.selected   { background-color: green; }
.clicked    { background-color: red; }
```

Then you can use them as follows:

```
<div id="test" class="unselected">test<div>
```

Then (in a document.ready or a script block after the test element):

```
$("#test").click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
      $this.removeClass("selected").addClass("clicked");
      // ajax here if needed
   } else if ($this.hasClass("clicked")) {
      $this.removeClass("clicked").addClass("selected");
      // ajax here if needed
   } else if ($this.hasClass("unselected")) {
      $this.removeClass("unselected").addClass("selected");
      // ajax here if needed
   }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LLCMa/

The above should be self explanatory. Of course you can put your Ajax call outside the if/else structure if that's more appropriate, but if you need to make different Ajax calls depending on the current state do as above.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this), clicked = $(this).hasClass('clicked');
    if (!clicked) {
        $this.addClass('clicked');
    } else {
        var isRed = $this.hasClass('red');
        $this.toggleClass('red', !isRed).toggleClass('green', isRed)
    }           
    // do ajax
})
```